# run batch and script file every 2 minutes instead of task scheduler

Tags: excel, batch-file, task, scheduler, vba

I have two tasks running using windows task scheduler. One is a batch file that extracts data from an application installed in my office computer and a script that opens a macro-enabled excel that retrieves the data that was ran then updates the html website I created. With using task scheduler, the fastest it can run is every 5minutes I'm trying to find out if there is any way that I can have these tasks run every 1-2 minutes instead? Please note, I'm still new to these so if you can explain it simpler terms and instructions, I'll highly appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command line to create that manual task if you don't mind.

```
schtasks /create /tn TaskName /tr TaskRun /sc minute [/mo {1 - 1439}] [/st     HH:MM] [/sd StartDate] [/ed EndDate] [{/et HH:MM | /du HHHH:MM} [/k]] [/it] [/ru {[Domain\]User [/rp Password] | System}] [/s Computer [/u [Domain\]User [/p Password]]]
```

[/mo {1 - 1439}] is the range of time you wish for it to run, the default is 1 minute.

If you want more info on custom task schedules [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785.aspx#BKMK_minutes) will have all that you should need.

Comment: You also might be able to workaround using task scheduler if you want to by just modifying your bat file to run in the background and go to a step every minute and repeat if you prefer. Either one of these should give you what you need.

Comment: Another option is to manually input "1 minute" in the "Repeat task every:" field. This should also work if that's the route you want to take.

Comment: How do you create a command line? Repeating the step would be a bit tedious in my part since I'd have other tasks to do. Upon checking, I don't have the option to manually input 1 minute, its just a dropbox and the fastest is 5 minutes.

Comment: Click in the dropdown box and you should be able to just type it in.

Comment: If your bat file runs in the background I would add this to the end before a loop TIMEOUT /T 60

Comment: Manually typing in the minute did work! Now I have it running on its own every 2minutes.